# Several skin in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I have two tinymce in the page

```html
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#comment',
    language: "fr",
    plugins: "image,autolink,autosave,stylebuttons,charmap,code,emoticons,fullscreen,hr,link,media,noneditable,powerpaste,preview,print,textcolor",
    skin: "lightgray",
    menubar:false,
    language : "fr",
    forced_root_block : false, // pour forcer le saut a la ligne
    toolbar: "bold italic| style-p style-h2 style-h3 style-h4 |  alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link media image | code | hr | emoticons forecolor backcolor | preview fullscreen",
   default_link_target: "_blank"
  });
 </script>

 <script>
 tinymce.init({
    selector: '#1', 
    language: "fr",
    plugins: "image,autolink,autosave,stylebuttons,charmap,code,emoticons,fullscreen,hr,link,media,noneditable,powerpaste,preview,print,textcolor",
    skin: "light",
    menubar:false,
    language : "fr",
    forced_root_block : false, // pour forcer le saut a la ligne
   toolbar: "bold italic |  alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link media image | charmap code | hr | emoticons forecolor backcolor | print | preview fullscreen",
   default_link_target: "_blank",
   height : 20
 });
</script>
```

I would like several skin in the same page.
Example skin: "lightgray" and skin: "light", but it's doesn'twork

Can I help me please

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you provide more details?  What does not work?  An example of this on TinyMCE Fiddle would greatly help people in understanding your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't know about TinyMCE Fiddle thanks

ok I understood

I can't have two skin in the same page, but I must have one skin with several variant
it's this?

thank you very much